# How to match price range using RegEx?

Tags: regex

I have a product feed with products that have prices ranging from 0 - 10000.

The product price is populated for each product.

I want to match products that have prices ranging from 0 - 1500 only using RegEx.

I have searched online to find out how to match numeric ranges, but I am struggling to figure out how to do it.

Can you tell me what RegEx should I use to match numeric values from 0 - 1500.

Thanks so much.

Comment: What language, and you do realize that regex may be the wrong tool for dealing with numeric comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Regex is bad at this, I'd recommend using another tool. That said, here's a regex that match numbers from 0 to 1500 included :

```
^(1(500|[0-4]\d\d)|\d{1,3})$
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this regular expression

```
^\d{1,3}$|^[0-1][0-4]\d{2}$|^1500$
```

**Explanation**

- Scenario 1: Starts and ends with a 1 to 3 digit number (000 through 999 or 0 through 999)
- Scenario 2: The first digit is either a 0 or 1, and the second digit can be in the range 0 through 4, followed by any 2 digits
- Scenario 3: The number 1500 exactly
- Matches: 0, 4, 39, 008, 1234, 1499, 1500
- Doesn't match: 1501, 15342

Play around with it here

https://regex101.com/r/yT6aY4/1

Comment: Wouldn't grouping the alternatives and writing the anchors once outside of the group be more readable? I.e. `^(\d{1,3}|[0-1][0-4]\d{2}|1500)$`

Comment: Nice catch, forgot about groups